# Doing an NDB IN query with an array

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to execute a query which I would intuitively have written as:

```
Project.query(Project.project_id IN ("abc","def")).fetch()
```

I have learned that in NDB, you do this instead:

```
Project.query(ndb.OR(Project.project_id == "abc", Project.project_id == "def")).fetch()
```

Which I'm generally fine with, even if it's a bit harder to read. Although (to a novice like me) I don't get why the interpreter can't do the hard work for you and accept / parse an IN into a nest of OR =='s... but that's a separate question.

The problem is that my list of acceptable project_id values - in this case "abc", "def" - is dynamic. With IN, I can wrap my head around something like IN list. With these multiple ORs, I guess I could iterate over my list and write out the chained statement - but that would be a string, so I suspect ndb wouldn't parse it as a valid query, and it feels super inelegant.

What's the canonical approach here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Google doc for IN](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in) has this example:

> query = Article.query(Article.tags.IN(['python', 'ruby', 'php']))

which suggests you should be able to do:

```
dynamic_list = ['abc','def','ghi']
Project.query(Project.project_id.IN(dynamic_list))
```

Comment: Got it! I thought the docs were saying that you had to write it in the second style. If the first (more traditional) style works (and it does) I much prefer that.